# Override hover transition on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New learner here!

I have a button, "New Quote", which when clicked, transitions the page contents to a new random color scheme over 1000ms. This button also has a jQuery hover effect that transitions its background-color to a darker shade over a 100ms delay when hovered.

When the link is clicked, the 100ms transition remains, causing the background-color of the button to transition to the new random color much quicker then the rest of the page.

Is there anyway to override the hover transition and replace it with the longer transition once the button is clicked?

Here is my JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  refreshQuote();
})

$(".newQuote").on("click", function() {
  refreshQuote();
})

function refreshQuote() {
  // Gets and assigns JSON
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://random-quote-generator.herokuapp.com/api/quotes/random',
    success: function(data){
      $("h1").html(data.quote);
      if (data.author !== undefined) {
        $("footer").html("- " + data.author);
      } else {
        $("footer").html("- Unknown");
      }
      $('.tweetQuote').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=' + data.quote + "%0A" + data.author);
    }
  })
  setColors();
}

// Assigns colors and hover effect
function setColors() {
  colors.randomArray();
  $("a, body").css("background-color", colors.normColor());
  $("a, .quote-container").css("border", "5px" + " " + "solid" + " " + colors.darkColor()) 
  $('.newHover').hover( 
    function() {
      $(".newHover").css("background-color", colors.darkColor()).css("transition", "background-color linear 100ms");
    }, 
    function() {
      $(".newHover").css("background-color", colors.normColor()).css("transition", "background-color linear 100ms");
    }) 
}

// Object to create multiple shades of random rgb()'s;
var colors = {
  colorArray: [],
  randomArray: function() {
    this.colorArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      this.colorArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    }
  },
  normColor: function() {
    var normColor = "rgb" + "(" + this.colorArray.join() + ")";
    return normColor;
  },
  darkColor: function() {
    var darkArray = [];
    this.colorArray.forEach(function(num) {
      darkArray.push(Math.floor(num / 1.5));
    });
    var darkColor = "rgb" + "(" + darkArray.join() + ")";
    return darkColor;
  }
}
```

And more importantly the link to the [codepen](http://codepen.io/adamaz1ng/pen/mmKKgg)

Thanks All!

Comment: Use `.stop()` to stop the animation on the element when you start the new animation?

Comment: @Barmar It's a CSS transition.

Comment: ummm, since the 100ms transition is in your code, why cant you just delete that line?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! I ended up using this in my click function and it solved the problem.

Comment: @Rooster I think I need the 100ms on hover in order to override the 1000ms that normally exists on the background color of the button. It seems I have to include transitions in my code because my color theme is determined randomly based on a on click function.

Comment: you dont need to use javascript to override css.  Just change the css.  If anything, all you need to do is add and remove a class with different css.

Comment: @Rooster Yes I agree, normally this would be the preferred method, but the rgb() values are randomly determined as a response to a click function and therefore can't exist in the css file unless css allowed using variables. At least I think this is the case. Also it turns out that the jquery .css() method cannot attach to a :hover selector for some reason. Perhaps there is a better way...

Answer (score 0):

"...new random color much quicker then the rest of the page."

That's due to where you are calling `setColors` from, you see it happens before your ajax's success callback gets triggered. That's asynchronous thinking.

So what I'll advice is put the `setColor()` within the `success` callback, probably just below the `$('.tweetQuote').attr('href', ...` line.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This didn't solve the specific issue, but you are correct that including the setColor() function within the callback did seem to improve performance overall. However I ended up including it as the first step, not the last. Thanks for your advice!